# How to test Retrofit API call using MockWebServer

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, retrofit, okhttp

I have a class that creates the RetrofitInstance in a very basic way, and I want to test that it is working correctly by running a dummy api against a mockedWebServer but for some reason Instead of getting a succesfull 200 response I get a 0.

```
fun createRetrofitInstance(baseUrl: String, client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(callAdapterFactory)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .client(client)
                .build()
}
```

and I want to test it using a DummyApi

```
@Test
    fun `should return successful response`() {
        val mockedWebServer = MockWebServer()
        val mockedResponse = MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
        mockedWebServer.enqueue(mockedResponse)
        mockedWebServer.start()
        mockedWebServer.url("/")

        val retrofit = tested.createRetrofitInstance(mockedWebServer.url("/").toString(), client)
        val testApi = retrofit.create(TestApi::class.java)

        val actualResponseCall: Call<Any> = testApi.getTestApi()
        assertEquals(200, actualResponseCall.execute().code())
        
        mockedWebServer.shutdown()
    }
```

DummyApi

```
interface TestApi { 
    @GET("/")
    fun getTestApi() : Call<Any>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read through one of the excellent tutorials on MockWebServer out there.  Too much information for just this answer. I think in this case you are just missing the `setBody` call.

https://medium.com/android-news/unit-test-api-calls-with-mockwebserver-d4fab11de847

```
val mockedResponse = MockResponse()
mockedResponse.setResponseCode(200)
mockedResponse.setBody("{}") // sample JSON
```

Comment: I thought .setBody(...) was optional but actually it is needed and helped me fix the test. I don't find the suggested tutorial helpful as it is not maintained and parts of the code are missing there, but indeed thanks.

Comment: There are a lot out there, I just picked the first one I found to grab some working sample code.  I'm glad it helped.